# Connection Test Query in Hikari

Tags: hikaricp

I am using a Hikari data source in my application and database kills all the connections which are idle for more than 15 mins. So i wanted to set a connection test query. How do I know when this query is fired and how can I log when this query is fired?

Comment: search `connectionTestQuery` here:https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby, also which db you are using and is that DB is jdbc4 compliant?